# How can rewrite about this java lambda expression?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Currently I learn Springboot.

```
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> collection = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        collection.add(()-> user.getRole().getKey());
        return collection;
    }
```

In this code

```
collection.add(()-> user.getRole().getKey());
```

I know this is lambda expression but I don't get raw code.
This is not my code.
Could you let me know the raw code?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "raw code" but since `collection.add` is expecting a `GrantedAuthority`, and `GrantedAuthority` has a single abstract method, the function defined by the lambda is inferred to be `GrantedAuthority::getAuthority`. i.e. the thing you're adding to that collection is a granted authority which always returns the role key of `user`, where `user` is presumably a field of this class (since you have haven't provided the definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is hard to follow because the collection is supposed to be a collection of `GrantedAuthority` objects. A `GrantedAuthority` is a single method `interface` with a `getAuthority()` function - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html#getAuthority()

So what the code is trying to do here is create a single element collection with a `GrantedAuthority` whose `getAuthority` method returns the value of `user.getRole().getKey()` - whatever that happens to be in this context.

You might find it easier to think of there being a single-use class here:

```
GrantedAuthority theOneAuthority = new GrantedAuthority() {
   String getAuthority() {
      return user.getRole().getKey();
   }
}
return List.of(theOneAuthority); // a single entry list
```

To understand the above, however, you'd need to understand the concept of an anonymous inner class - in other words a temporary type whose job it is to subclass an interface or other class to do something a particular method wants us to do.

In this instance, a lambda is a better alternative.

```
// as there's only one method, taking 0 parameters and returning string
// then this 0 parameter string-returning lambda can BE a `GrantedAuthority`
GrantedAuthority authFromLambda = () -> user.getRole().getKey();
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some types of lambda expressions:

1. (int x, int y) -> { return x + y; }
2. x -> x * x
3. ( ) -> x

So, your case is third one. It is used when you get no parameters as a method arguments and return a value. In your example, it just returns the value of `user.getRole().getKey());` and it added to the `Collection<GrantedAuthority>`

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that saying there are 3 types, or at best I don't think that's a helpful way to think about it. How about `x -> { return x * x; }`? More precisely, the LHS has several forms (with/without brackets, with/without types), and the RHS has several forms (expression/block). I make that 8 possible "types", right?

Comment: ok, I didn't mean that 3 types at all, I corrected it